# Getting "java.lang.IllegalStateException: Tried to lookup lag for unknown task 3_0" after upgrading Kafka Stream from 2.5.1 to 2.6.2

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

I just upgraded our Kafka Stream application from 2.5.1 to 2.6.2. It used to work, now it doesn't.

Here is the troublesome topology (I have omitted the irrelevant Serdes):

```scala
val builder = new StreamsBuilder()

val contractEventStream: KStream[TariffId, ContractEvent] =
   builder.stream[String, ContractUpsertAvro](settings.contractsTopicName)
     .flatMap { (_, contractAvro) =>
       ContractEvent.from(contractAvro)
         .map(contractEvent => (contractEvent.tariffId, contractEvent))
      }

    val tariffsTable: KTable[TariffId, Tariff] =
      builder.stream[String, TariffUpdateEventAvro](settings.tariffTopicName)
        .flatMapValues(Tariff.fromAvro(_))
        .selectKey((_, tariff) => tariff.tariffId)
        .toTable(Materialized.`with`(tariffIdSerde, tariffSerde)) // Materialized.as also throws the same IllegalStateExceptions

    contractEventStream
      .join(tariffsTable)(JourneyStep.from(_, _).asInstanceOf[ContractCreated])(Joined.`with`(tariffIdSerde, contractEventSerde, tariffSerde))
      .selectKey((_, contractUpdated) => contractUpdated.accountId)
      .foreach((_, journeyStep) => println(journeyStep))
```

The join gives the following exception:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Tried to lookup lag for unknown task 3_0
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.assignment.ClientState.lagFor(ClientState.java:306)
    at java.util.Comparator.lambda$comparingLong$6043328a$1(Comparator.java:511)
    at java.util.Comparator.lambda$thenComparing$36697e65$1(Comparator.java:216)
    at java.util.TreeMap.compare(TreeMap.java:1295)
    at java.util.TreeMap.put(TreeMap.java:538)
    at java.util.TreeSet.add(TreeSet.java:255)
    at java.util.AbstractCollection.addAll(AbstractCollection.java:344)
    at java.util.TreeSet.addAll(TreeSet.java:312)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamsPartitionAssignor.getPreviousTasksByLag(StreamsPartitionAssignor.java:1275)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamsPartitionAssignor.assignTasksToThreads(StreamsPartitionAssignor.java:1189)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamsPartitionAssignor.computeNewAssignment(StreamsPartitionAssignor.java:940)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamsPartitionAssignor.assign(StreamsPartitionAssignor.java:399)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.ConsumerCoordinator.performAssignment(ConsumerCoordinator.java:589)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.AbstractCoordinator.onJoinLeader(AbstractCoordinator.java:684)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.AbstractCoordinator.access$1000(AbstractCoordinator.java:111)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.AbstractCoordinator$JoinGroupResponseHandler.handle(AbstractCoordinator.java:597)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.AbstractCoordinator$JoinGroupResponseHandler.handle(AbstractCoordinator.java:560)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.AbstractCoordinator$CoordinatorResponseHandler.onSuccess(AbstractCoordinator.java:1160)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.AbstractCoordinator$CoordinatorResponseHandler.onSuccess(AbstractCoordinator.java:1135)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.RequestFuture$1.onSuccess(RequestFuture.java:206)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.RequestFuture.fireSuccess(RequestFuture.java:169)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.RequestFuture.complete(RequestFuture.java:129)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.ConsumerNetworkClient$RequestFutureCompletionHandler.fireCompletion(ConsumerNetworkClient.java:602)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.ConsumerNetworkClient.firePendingCompletedRequests(ConsumerNetworkClient.java:412)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.ConsumerNetworkClient.poll(ConsumerNetworkClient.java:297)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.ConsumerNetworkClient.poll(ConsumerNetworkClient.java:236)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer.pollForFetches(KafkaConsumer.java:1296)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer.poll(KafkaConsumer.java:1237)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer.poll(KafkaConsumer.java:1210)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamThread.pollRequests(StreamThread.java:767)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamThread.runOnce(StreamThread.java:624)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamThread.runLoop(StreamThread.java:551)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamThread.run(StreamThread.java:510)
```

I can't see what I am doing wrong. The code above works with Kafka 2.5.1. Anyone has any idea what is going on?

Comment: I vaguely recall that you need to run the application-reset script if you're running into issues with upgrading streams versions https://kafka.apache.org/26/documentation/streams/upgrade-guide

Comment: Is this the result of a rolling upgrade? Or did you stop all Streams instances, upgrade them and restart them?

Comment: @BrunoCadonna I stopped all the instances and upgrade them.

Comment: Could you add the topology description (use topology.describe().toString()) for 2.5.1 and 2.6.2 to your question? Are you sure you upgraded all instances before you restarted?

Answer (score 14):

The problem is caused by the Kafka Streams cache, which it keeps on disk. This cache is specific to Kafka-version and to the Kafka Streams topology you use (ie. a change in your topology could also lead to this error).

The cache is usually found in /tmp or elsewhere if you passed in the "state.dir" property to Kafka Streams. Clear the directory with the cache and you should be able to cleanly start again.

Comment: Saved my day ! On MacOS it resides in `/private/tmp/kafka-streams`